# How to place a label in the bottom-left corner of application using float layout in kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, label, kivy, python-3.7

## Goal:

- To anchor the label to the bottom-left using FloatLayout.

---

### Expected Result:

- The label must be on the bottom-left corner with a single line.

---

### Actual Result:

- The label is on the bottom-left but it is double-lined.

---

### The code for reference:

```py
class ScreenThree(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScreenThree, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.video1 = Video(source="somevideo.mpg")
        float_layout = FloatLayout()
        self.label1 = Label(text="Just a place holder video", opacity=0, pos_hint={"x": 0, "bottom": 1}, size_hint=[0.1, 0.1])
        self.label1.texture_size = self.label1.size
        self.label1.text_size = self.label1.texture_size
        self.label1.halign = "center"
        self.label1.valign = "center"
        self.add_widget(float_layout)
        float_layout.add_widget(self.label1)
        float_layout.add_widget(self.video1, index=1)
        self.video1.opacity = 0

    def on_enter(self):
        self.video1.allow_stretch = True
        self.video1.state = "play"
        self.label1.opacity = 1
        Clock.schedule_once(self._adjust_opacity, 2)

    def _adjust_opacity(self, *dt):
        self.video1.opacity = 1
```

---

### The Image for reference:

[image: Just a picture!]

---

#### Thank you very much for reading.

Comment: **Just to know!**
Do you want to credited for my game?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your line:

```
    self.label1 = Label(text="Just a place holder video", opacity=0, pos_hint={"x": 0, "bottom": 1}, size_hint=[0.1, 0.1])
```

Just change the `size_hint` to `[None, 0.1]`:

```
    self.label1 = Label(text="Just a place holder video", opacity=1, pos_hint={"x": 0, "bottom": 1}, size_hint=[None, 0.1])
```

and remove the lines:

```
    self.label1.texture_size = self.label1.size
    self.label1.text_size = self.label1.texture_size
    self.label1.halign = "center"
    self.label1.valign = "center"
```

Comment: The answer doesn't work but it worked when I change it `0.2`